# Is it possible to compile a smart contract using g++ or clang?

Tags: smart-contract, c++, compilation, unit-tests

I want to write and execute some unit tests on a smart contract outside of nodeos, but to do that I need to be able to compile the code the normal C++ way, using g++ or clang, so that I get object or assembly files as output, i.e. `mycontract.o` or `mycontract.s`

So far I've been trying to mock the elements that are specific to EOS, but it isn't easy.

Does anyone know of a way to compile the code with clang or g++? Alternatively any tricks that would help in this situation would also be appreciated.

Comment: yeah, check out the video from OCI. heifner goes over his setup at the beginning https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3Tx2DseLGE

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I watched the video but unless I missed it he does **not** explain how to compile using `clang` or `g++`. He only shows how to set up the environments in his IDE correctly so that you can compile with `eosiocpp`

Comment: at 16:11 he shows cmake options and at 42:30 says he can build from his IDE without using `eosiocpp` no?

Comment: or, alternatively, this article seems to go over something similar https://infinitexlabs.com/setup-ide-for-eos-development/ unless this is not at all what you're looking for haha

Comment: The biggest drawback to that approach is AFAIK you can't test time passing like you can with Boost tests. That is important for contracts that want to implement time delays for things like staking/unstaking tokens for example.

Answer (score 2):

With `eosio.cdt`, it is now possible to compile object code which can then be tested using unit tests. Check out https://eosio.github.io/eosio.cdt/1.5.0/guides/native-tester.html for a detailed guide.

Below is the quoted text from the link at the time of writing this answer (in case the web page is moved or something)

> ## Native Tester/Compilation
>
> As of v1.5.0 native compilation can be
>   performed and a new set of libraries to facilitate native testing and
>   native "scratch pad" compilation. `eosio-cc\cpp` and `eosio-ld` now
>   support building "smart contracts" and unit tests natively for quick
>   tests to help facilitate faster development (note the default
>   implementations of eosio `intrinsics` are currently asserts that state
>   they are unavailable, these are user definable.)
>
> Getting Started Once you have your smart contract written then a test
>   source file can be written.
>
> hello.hpp
>
> ```
> #include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
>
> using namespace eosio;
>
> CONTRACT hello : public eosio::contract {   public:
>       using contract::contract;
>
>       ACTION hi( name user );
>
>       // accessor for external contracts to easily send inline actions to your contract
>       using hi_action = action_wrapper<"hi"_n, &hello::hi>; };
> ```
>
> and then a quick test `hello_test.cpp`
>
> ```
> #include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
> #include <eosio/native/tester.hpp>
>
> #include <hello.hpp>
>
> using namespace eosio; using namespace eosio::native;
>
> EOSIO_TEST_BEGIN(hello_test)    // These can be redefined by the user
> to suit there needs per unit test    // the idea is that in a future
> release we will have a base library that     // initializes these to
> "useable" default implementations and probably     // helpers to more
> easily define read_action_data and action_data_size intrinsics    //
> like these"   
> intrinsics::set_intrinsic<intrinsics::read_action_data>(
>          [](void* m, uint32_t len) {
>             check(len <= sizeof(eosio::name), "failed from read_action_data");
>             *((eosio::name*)m) = "hello"_n;
>             return len; 
>          });
>
>    intrinsics::set_intrinsic<intrinsics::action_data_size>(
>          []() {
>             return (uint32_t)sizeof(eosio::name);
>          });
>
>    intrinsics::set_intrinsic<intrinsics::require_auth>(
>          [](capi_name nm) {
>          });
>
>
>    // "Name : hello" should be in the print buffer   
> CHECK_PRINT("Name : hello",
>          []() {
>             apply("test"_n.value, "test"_n.value, "hi"_n.value);
>             });
>
>    // should not assert    apply("test"_n.value, "test"_n.value,
> "check"_n.value);
>
>    name nm = "null"_n;   
> intrinsics::set_intrinsic<intrinsics::read_action_data>(
>          [&](void* m, uint32_t len) {
>             check(len <= sizeof(eosio::name), "failed from read_action_data");
>             *((eosio::name*)m) = nm;
>             return len; 
>          });
>
>    REQUIRE_ASSERT( "check name not equal to `hello`",
>          []() {
>             // should assert
>             apply("test"_n.value, "test"_n.value, "check"_n.value);
>             });
>
> EOSIO_TEST_END
>
>  // boilerplate main, this will be generated in a future release int
>  main(int argc, char** argv) {    silence_output(true);   
>  EOSIO_TEST(hello_test);    return has_failed(); }
> ```
>
> Every `intrinsic` that
>    is defined for eosio (prints, require_auth, etc.) is redefinable
>   given  the
>   `intrinsics::set_intrinsics<intrinsics::the_intrinsic_name>()` 
>   functions. These take a lambda whose arguments and return type should 
>   match that of the `intrinsic` you are trying to define. This gives the
>   contract writer the flexibility to modify behavior to suit the unit 
>   test being written. A sister function 
>   `intrinsics::get_intrinsics<intrinsics::the_intrinsic_name>()` will 
>   return the function object that currently defines the behavior for 
>   said intrinsic. This pattern can be used to mock functionality and 
>   allow for easier testing of smart contracts. For more information 
>   please see, either the ./tests directory or 
>   ./examples/hello/tests/hello_test.cpp for working examples.
>
> ## Compiling Native Code
>
> - Raw `eosio-cpp` to compile the test or program the only addition    needed to the command line is to add the flag `-fnative` this will
>     then    generate native code instead of wasm code.
> - Via CMake: add_native_library and add_native_executable CMake macros    have been added (these are a drop in replacement for
>     add_library and    add_executable).
>
> ## Eosio.CDT Native Tester API
>
> `CHECK_ASSERT(...)` : This macro will check whether a particular
>   assert has occured and flag the tests as failed but allow the rest of
>   the tests to run. This is called either by
>
> - `CHECK_ASSERT("<assert message>", [](<args>){    whatever_function(<args>); })`
> - `CHECK_ASSERT([](std::string msg){ user defined comparison function    }, [](<args>){ whatever_function(<args>); })`
>
> `CHECK_PRINT(...)` : This macro will check whether the print buffer
>   holds the string that is expected and flag the tests as failed but
>   allow the rest of the test to run. This is called either by
>
> - `CHECK_PRINT("<print message>", [](<args>){    whatever_function(<args>); })`
> - `CHECK_PRINT([](std::string print_buffer){ user defined comparison    function }, [](<args>){ whatever_function(<args>); })`
>
> `CHECK_EQUAL(X, Y)`: This macro will check whether two inputs equal
>   each other and fail the test but allow the rest of the test to
>   continue.
>
> `REQUIRE_ASSERT(...)` : This macro will check whether a particular
>   assert has occured and flag the tests as failed and halt the test on
>   failure. This is called either by
>
> - `REQUIRE_ASSERT("<assert message>", [](<args>){    whatever_function(<args>); })`
> - `REQUIRE_ASSERT([](std::string msg){ user defined comparison function    }, [](<args>){ whatever_function(<args>); })`
>
> `REQUIRE_PRINT(...)` : This macro will check whether the print buffer
>   holds the string that is expected and flag the tests as failed and
>   halt the test on failure. This is called either by
>
> - `REQUIRE_PRINT("<print message>", [](<args>){    whatever_function(<args>); })`
> - `REQUIRE_PRINT([](std::string print_buffer){ user defined comparison    function }, [](<args>){ whatever_function(<args>); })`
>
> `REQUIRE_EQUAL(X, Y)` : This macro will check whether two inputs X and
>   Y equal eachother and fail the test and halt the test on failure.
>
> `EOSIO_TEST_BEGIN(X)` : This macro defines the beginning of a unit
>   test and assigns X as the symbolic name of that test.
>
> `EOSIO_TEST_END` : This macro defines the end of a unit test.
>
> `EOSIO_TEST(X)` : This is used to run a particular named unit test X
>   in the main function.